# Count number of integer tuple

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have $n$ integer constants $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ and $n$  integer variables $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ with following conditions: 
$$ 
\begin{align}
& 0 \leq x_1 \leq c_1, \\
& \vdots  \\
& 0 \leq x_n \leq c_n;
\end{align}
$$
and 
$$ x_1 \leq \cdots \leq x_n. $$

How to count the number of integer $n$-tuples $\left( x_1, \ldots, x_n \right)$ that satisfy all the above conditions?

I can use the for-loop in a programming language to count. But with some large values of $a$, $b$, $c$, it takes very long time to finish counting (For example $a = b = c = 1000000$).

Please help me to find a concrete formula for this problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You may want to start out by looking up "stars and bars", which I think will probably form the basis of an answer.

Comment: You count the tuples, not the number of tuples.

Comment: Thank @Saaqib Mahmood for making the question clear

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a sketch of a recursive approach.  It may not be the simplest.

We may as well assume $c_1 \le c_2 \le c_3 \le \ldots c_n$.  If not, reduce the earlier ones so it is true, because if $c_3 \gt c_4$ there are still no acceptable tuples with $x_3 \gt c_4$

Now if $x_2 \gt c_1$ we have $c_1+1$ choices for $x_1$ with the rest of the tuple, so solve the problem removing $x_1$ and subtracting $c_1+1$ from all the later $c$'s, then multiply the resulting answer by $c_1+1$.

If $x_2 \le c_1$ we have the same problem with $c_2$ replaced by $c_1$.  If $x_3\gt c_1$ we need the number of pairs less than $c_1$ for the first two times the number of tuples of length $n-2$ for the end.  Subtract $c_1+1$ from each of the last $n+2\ c$'s and solve the problem.

We have now reduced the problem to the number of increasing tuples of length $k$ with the same maximum $c_1$ for each entry.  We can use stars and bars to see there are $k-1 \choose m-1$ ways to choose the duplicate entries if there are $m$ distinct values.  There are $c_1 \choose m$ ways to choose the values, so there are $\sum_{m=1}^k{k-1 \choose m-1}{c_1 \choose m}$ solutions.

Comment: Thanks Ross for a very nice recursive solution.

Comment: I expected a concrete formula for this problem to obtain O(1) complexity. But it seems that we cannot have that kind of formula.

Comment: Somebody else might have a better idea.  I had fun with the problem and this is the best I found.  My next step would be to do the final sum for small $c_1$ and see if there seemed to be a closed form it.  I would not accept this answer so quickly as it may scare others off.

Comment: Thank Ross. I just undo the acceptance :). The problem seems to have the multiple integral form (discrete). I tried to apply some continuous integral formulas but the result was not correct.